# Iterative IF condition in For Loop assigned to Matrix

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I am trying to assign values from one worksheet (DATA) to a matrix (TaskArray()) using nested for loops. My issue is that the IF statement, when met, will be assigned to all values in the appropriate TaskArray() row. How do I set singular IF (or boolean) conditions in nested for loops that only get recognized once?

```
Dim TaskArray(1 to 10, 1 to 300) as String

For i = 1 to 300
   For j = 1 to 10
   If Sheets("DATA").Cells(i,1).Value = TRUE Then
   TaskArray(1, AA) = Sheets("DATA").Cells(i,4).Value
   AA = AA + 1

   If Sheets("DATA").Cells(i,2).Value = TRUE Then
   TaskArray(1, BB) = Sheets("DATA").Cells(i,4).Value
   BB = BB + 1
End if
Next j
Next i
```

Thank you!

Comment: add some screenshots of what do you want to accomplish

Comment: doesn't seem like that can compile. There are 2 `If` and only 1 `End If`

Comment: And `j` is not being used .. it's just repeating the same code 10 times ..